# Google Translate html widget not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

I inserted a piece of code I found to put flag widgets powered by Google Translate to be able to have a website in more languages. And whilst the flags do appear and it seems that the cursor recognises this as a link, when testing it (without having uploaded it) on Chrome I click the flags and nothing happens.
Do I need to upload it in order for it to work or is it an issue in the code?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm quite new to all this :)

The code:

```
`<script language="JavaScript"> <!-- 
document.write ("<input name=u value="+location.href+" type=hidden>") 
// --> 
</script>
<input name="hl" value="es" type="hidden">
<input name="ie" value="UTF8" type="hidden">
<input name="langpair" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="langpair" value="es|en" title="English" src="images/UK.gif" onclick="this.form.langpair.value=this.value" height="20" type="image" width="30">
<input name="langpair" value="es|pt" title="Portuguese" src= "http://photos1.blogger.com/img/43/1633/320/13539966_0d09b410b5.jpg" onclick="this.form.langpair.value=this.value" height="20" type="image" width="30">
<input name="langpair" value="es|fr" title="French" src= "http://photos1.blogger.com/img/43/1633/320/13539949_e76af75976.jpg" onclick="this.form.langpair.value=this.value" height="20" type="image" width="30">
<input name="langpair" value="es|de" title="German" src= "http://photos1.blogger.com/img/43/1633/320/13539933_041ca1eda2.jpg" onclick="this.form.langpair.value=this.value" height="20" type="image" width="30">
<input name="langpair" value="es|it" title="Italian" src= "http://photos1.blogger.com/img/43/1633/320/13539953_0384ccecf9.jpg" onclick="this.form.langpair.value=this.value" height="20" type="image" width="30">
<input name="langpair2" value="es|ar" title="Arabic" src= "http://photos1.blogger.com/blogger/3709/485/1600/arabic-flag.gif" onclick="this.form.langpair.value=this.value" height="20" type="image" width="30" />
</form>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the open form tag, first thing, before `<script ...`:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/translate" >
```

I tested from a local file and pressing the flags sends you to `translate.google.com`.

However, Google has to have access to your HTML page in order to translate it, so this widget is only functional on public websites on the Internet. It does not seem to work locally or in Intranet sites.